# how to delete unwanted rows from csv in python?

Tags: python, csv

I have csv file `abc.csv` with two columns `Name` & `ID` and list of ids `l_id`. Now I want to delete all those rows from csv where `ID` not in `l_id`. I have tried the following:

```
l_id=[18850080, 535553, 19292162, 1728035, 1179719, 19194894, 22817838, 19997487, 19728145, 1457232, 13560402, 18855476, 7151442, 18955830, 11294262, 18506072, 1360698]

       Name    ID
0     2069     19277993
1     625050   19277900
2     1939496  19277793
3     2606806  19275471
4     3438546  19273652
5     4211111  7151442
6     4353024  19200001
7     5175848  11294262
8     5300858  1360698
9     5636006  535553
10    5729989  19277800
11    6045513  19277320
12    6160486  19277458
13    6540851  19276852
14    6752008  19277363
15    7643395  19997487
16    7644736  19292162
17    7712083  19292100
18    7768516  19292169
19    7809273  1360698



with open('abc.csv', 'r') as inp, open('abc_edit.csv', 'w') as out:
    writer = csv.writer(out)
    for line in inp:
        if (set(line.split()).isdisjoint(set(l_id)))==False:
            writer.writerow(line)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use pandas `isin` function

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('csv_name')
```

take only rows where those I_id exists in ID columns

```
df = df.loc[df['ID'].isin(I_id)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert `l_ids` to a set first, and use a generator expression in the `writerows` method of the CSV writer to include those with `id` in the set:

```
ids = set(l_id)
with open('abc.csv', 'r') as inp, open('abc_edit.csv', 'w') as out:
    reader = csv.reader(inp)
    writer = csv.writer(out)
    writer.writerow(next(reader)) # write the header unconditionally
    writer.writerows(name, id for name, id in reader if int(id) in ids)
```